# Complex log problem. How do I find the answer?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this problem and I'm trying to solve and find all values:

$$(1+i)^{2-i}$$

So far I have

$$1 + i = \sqrt{2} e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4})}$$ I got the above by converting 1+i into polar form. Also:

$$1+i = e^{ln(1+i)}$$

$$(1+i)^{2-i} = e^{(2-i)*ln(1+i)}$$

Now what?

Comment: How do you define $(1+i)^{2-i}$ ?

Comment: You can be more specific and I cannot. Just write it out what you mean. Why does everyone think this is the best way to teach? I clearly don't understand the concept or the topic or even what to google so help me out here if you want but don't be difficult.

Comment: I mean that there is not a unique way to define what a power of complex numbers mean. So you should precise how you define $a^b$, for $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, if you want us to understand your question and help you.

Comment: sorry misunderstood then

Answer (score 1):

Let $w=1+i$ and $z=2-i$. Then, as you noted, for any choice of log (there are countably many), we have $w^z=e^{z\log w}$. As you noted, in polar coordinates, $w=\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$. Therefore, the set of logarithms is the family
\begin{align}
\log w&=\ln r + i(Arg(w)+2k\pi), \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}\\
&=\ln (\sqrt{2}) + i\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi \right), \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}
In general, taking complex bases to complex powers yields varying results. The point of the exercise is to see how many truly distinct values of $w^z$ are possible.

For example, suppose $z=n$, for some positive integer $n$. Then
\begin{align}
e^{z\log w}&=e^{n\left[\ln (\sqrt{2}) + i\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi \right)\right]} \\
&=e^{n\left[\ln (\sqrt{2}) + i\frac{\pi}{4}\right]}\underbrace{e^{2kn\pi i}}_{=1}
\end{align}
so even though we can choose any log, there is always one output.

In your case, $z=2-i$. Multiply that through the logarithm set and see if any of the terms of the form $e$ to an even integer times $\pi$ times $i$ pop out.